# How do I get a list of ONLY user-created fields in a SharePoint 2007 List via C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Hello and thanks for looking!

## Background

I currently have a C# method for looping through a SharePoint List Collection and returning a lists of those SP Lists, including a nested list of their columns/SPFields.

## Problem

How do I get a list of ONLY user-created fields in a SharePoint 2007 List via C#?

## Code so far. . .

```
SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
        SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPListCollection lists = web.Lists;

        var PellaListCollection = new List<PellaListModel>();
        
        foreach (SPList l in lists) {
                var PellaList = new PellaListModel();
                var PellaListColumns = new List<PellaListColumn>();
                foreach (SPField c in l.Fields) {
                    if (c.Hidden.Equals(false))
                    {
                        var type = c.FieldTypeDefinition.TypeName.ToString();
                        var col = new PellaListColumn
                        {
                            ColumnId = c.Id,
                            ColumnDataType = type,
                            ColumnTitle = c.Title
                        };
                        PellaListColumns.Add(col);
                    }
                }
                PellaList.ListColumns = PellaListColumns;
                PellaList.ListId = l.ID;
                PellaList.ListTitle = l.Title;
                PellaList.Description = l.Description;
                PellaListCollection.Add(PellaList);
        }
        
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

        return PellaListCollection;
    }
```

As you can see, right now I am filtering by which SPFields are not "Hidden", but this still returns quite a few of the standard SharePoint generated fields with the list.  I just need the fields the users have created.

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: Are you trying to get at Users Info..? or a custom user list that users have each created..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [FromBaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.frombasetype.aspx) property of `SPField`.  This property is true if the field is part of the original schema for the List.

Check out this good [SharePoint Exchange article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11090/is-there-a-way-to-see-if-an-spfield-was-created-by-a-user) for more.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially test the SourceId in the SPField.

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.sourceid.aspx):

"Gets either the namespace that defines a built-in field or, if it a custom field, the GUID that identifies the list or Web site where it was created."

Comment: Thanks as always competent_tech, but Steve's answer was just what I needed.